# Jinja2 children

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to output data from the children of each item. Below is the template, output, expected output and data being passed.

template.html:

```
{% for item in data %}
    <h3>{{ item }}</h3>

    {% for task in item.children %}
        {{ task.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
<h3>Web</h3>

<h3>Mobile</h3>
```

Expected output:

```
<h3>Web</h3>
Homepage
Register

<h3>Mobile</h3>
Signup
Login
```

Data passed to template:

```
{
  "Web": [
    {
      "name": "Homepage", 
      "followers": [
        {
          "id": 53670274409
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Register", 
      "followers": [
        {
          "id": 53670274410
        }
      ]
    }, 
  ],
  "Web": [
    {
      "name": "Signup", 
      "followers": [
        {
          "id": 53670274409
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Login", 
      "followers": [
        {
          "id": 53670274410
        }
      ]
    }, 
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over a dictionary you will only get the keys, you can use `.items()` to get the values as well:

```
{% for item, children in data.items() %}
    <h3>{{ item }}</h3>

    {% for c in children %}
        {{ c.name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```